# Ubuntu Server 18.04 setting WiFi connections when install

Tags: server, wireless, 18.04, connection

I want to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 with WiFi connection, but there are no WiFi interface options, how can I do now ?

[image]

Comment: That's why I keep a long Ethernet cable specifically for installing Linux.

Comment: By the way, after you cope with the network configuration you will find out the installer of 18.04 doesn't list existing partitions for you to configure: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1750645

Comment: Yep, I finally finished with a cable.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the [older version of the installer](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/) aka. "the d-i installer". When I say "older version", it's still an installer for Ubuntu Server 18.04, it just uses the installer framework ("d-i") used by previous versions of Ubuntu. The newer installer framework ("subiquity") is very much a work-in-progress right now.

This information came from comment #5 on [bug #1750645](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/subiquity/+bug/1750645), linked in a comment on the question. As it notes, the [server download page](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) has a link to [alternative downloads](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads), and *that* has a section further down the page saying:

> If you require advanced networking and storage features such as; LVM, RAID, multipath, vlans, bonds, or re-using existing partitions, you will want to continue to use the alternate installer.

...which links to the [d-i-based installer downloads](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/).

Comment: thx for reply, I solved it by using Ethernet cable.

Comment: Still might be useful for others!

Comment: @detly Thank you. That helped. Downloaded from the "alternative downloads"

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the network bug but after re-partitioning with full formats AND adding EFI space (500MB is what I used), the installation found my wifi and I never saw a single window discussing network connections. I can't explain much of it but the EFI partition as the first one solved my frustration.